# Range for the result of the %mod operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, pymongo, database

For the document like this :

```
{
            cartId : 11,
            items : [{
                    itemId : 1,
                    et : 100
                }, {
                    itemId : 2,
                    et : 200
                }, {
                    itemId : 3,
                    et : 300
                }
            ]
}
```

I want to generate a query which will filter

```
Select * from Carts
where CartId%100 > 10 && 
CartId%100 <= 20
```

I know I can do this using $where, but can I do it also using $mod ?

mongoDB documentation link for the same : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/mod/

Answer (score 0):

No-- unfortunately, the `$mod` operator cannot take a range as a possible remainder.